# Ideal location for settlement on Bishop Ring Space habitat

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, space-colonization, habitats

let's take a Bishop Ring, with a diameter of approximately 1800km, 460km wide and with retention walls 150 km tall. At the centre of the ring there is an artificial sun that recreates a day/night cycle.

I presume that the flat habitable surface of the habitat would be pretty homogenous in terms of physics and weather. So, setting aside the location of sources of water, key infrastructures ecc... there are no specific reasons to place a settlement in a place rather than in another.

Is my presumption correct or, in a Bishop Ring like that described above, there can be important differences between, for instance, a settlement near the retention wall of the ring and one right in the middle of the habitable surface, let's say at approximately 200kms from each wall?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Close votes without comments are fairly unhelpful, folks. Please give people some actionable feedback rather than leaving them to gamble on their question being reopened again in the future.

Comment: Anyway, for my two centavos, you haven't defined any metric by which "ideal" could be measured. That makes it awkward to give a good answer to the question.

Comment: The ideal (better/worse) place of close/far to the Wall would depend on the parameters of whatever is "artificial sun", whether it casts enough energy on the wall, thermal insulation of the wall and whatever climate that would appear within. I assume that there would be more rain closer to the walls than in the center, yet if there would be too much rain, placing the settlement somewhere away from the wall would be better.

Comment: Should indicate is the people doing the settling have the ring tech or just some people who don't and happen to live there, The more fundamental problem with this question is that it is essentially a brainstorming question. What are the criteria for a good location?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I think I have received a good answer already. The question is about whether in this environment the location of a settlement would be indifferent in terms of physical/environmental conditions or if there would be areas which, like on Earth, are better than others to found a settlement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Presumably there will be some difference in climate.**

The angle of light from the artificial sun is different near the edge. about 22deg with your given dimensions. Unless otherwise compensated in the design of the light source, this will create a heat gradient in the ring. This will create convection in the atmosphere. And that means a zone with rising air in the middle with rain and two zones with falling air near the walls that are dry.

The presence of large surfaces of water might influence the weather, and so do differences of surface albedo. I don't think this will create storms and such, but the climate will not be the same everywhere.

Comment: Now I recognize your name. Hello again!

Comment: Hello man. Thanks for help... I have just signed a contract for a novel, but I feel I am missing details in the world building... oh no...